# How to import existing lambda from arn and add SQS as event source? Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-cdk, aws-amplify-cli

I'm trying to create an SNS topic that an SQS queue subscribes to which acts as an event source for a Lambda function. I'm trying to do this with the amplify cdk integration. However, there seems to be some problem when trying to reference the function which results in a permission problem.

> CREATE_FAILED fetchMetadataSqsEventSourcesqsqueue2144E8FE AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping Fri May 06 2022 17:20:15 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: The provided execution role does not have permissions to call ReceiveMessage on SQS (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 2b3147b0-8f59-4c35-8f0f-b7c29a45f139, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: c03cf5fb-283b-6d83-93c0-f7ee018338cd, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Here's my code

```js
import * as AmplifyHelpers from "@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper"
import * as iam from "@aws-cdk/aws-iam"
import * as lambda from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda"
import { SqsEventSource } from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources"
import * as sns from "@aws-cdk/aws-sns"
import * as subs from "@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions"
import * as sqs from "@aws-cdk/aws-sqs"
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core"
import { Duration } from "@aws-cdk/core"

import { AmplifyDependentResourcesAttributes } from "../../types/amplify-dependent-resources-ref"

export class cdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(
    scope: cdk.Construct,
    id: string,
    props?: cdk.StackProps,
    amplifyResourceProps?: AmplifyHelpers.AmplifyResourceProps
  ) {
    super(scope, id, props)

    /* Do not remove - Amplify CLI automatically injects the current deployment environment in this input parameter */
    new cdk.CfnParameter(this, "env", {
      type: "String",
      description: "Current Amplify CLI env name",
    })
    /* AWS CDK code goes here - learn more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html */

    // Example 1: Set up an SQS queue with an SNS topic

    const amplifyProjectInfo = AmplifyHelpers.getProjectInfo()
    const sqsQueueResourceNamePrefix = `sqs-queue-${amplifyProjectInfo.projectName}`
    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, "sqs-queue", {
      queueName: `${sqsQueueResourceNamePrefix}-${cdk.Fn.ref("env")}`,
      visibilityTimeout: Duration.seconds(30), // default,
      receiveMessageWaitTime: Duration.seconds(20), // default
    })

    // create sns topic
    const snsTopicResourceNamePrefix = `sns-topic-${amplifyProjectInfo.projectName}`
    const topic = new sns.Topic(this, "sns-topic", {
      topicName: `${snsTopicResourceNamePrefix}-${cdk.Fn.ref("env")}`,
    })

    //  subscribe queue to topic
    topic.addSubscription(new subs.SqsSubscription(queue))
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "snsTopicArn", {
      value: topic.topicArn,
      description: "The arn of the SNS topic",
    })

    const dependencies: AmplifyDependentResourcesAttributes =
      AmplifyHelpers.addResourceDependency(
        this,
        amplifyResourceProps.category,
        amplifyResourceProps.resourceName,
        [
          {
            category: "function", // api, auth, storage, function, etc.
            resourceName: "fetchMetadata", // find the resource at "amplify/backend/<category>/<resourceName>"
          } /* add more dependencies as needed */,
        ]
      )

    const fetchMetadataFnArn = cdk.Fn.ref(
      dependencies.function.fetchMetadata.Arn
    )

    const lambdaRole = new iam.Role(this, "Role", {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
      description: "Example role...",
    })

    queue.grantConsumeMessages(lambdaRole)

    let fn = lambda.Function.fromFunctionAttributes(this, "fetchMetadata", {
      role: lambdaRole,
      functionArn: fetchMetadataFnArn,
    })

    queue.grantConsumeMessages(fn)

    const eventSource = new SqsEventSource(queue)
    fn.addEventSource(eventSource)
  }
}
```

Here's a snippet of the generated CloudFormation code, it seems like there might be an issue with the arn? [image]

Comment: `fn.addEventSource(eventSource)` won't work, inported resources in CDK cannot be updated

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It will work with the right imported ARNs. You are right that _"imported resources in CDK cannot be updated"_.  But the CDK works around this constraint. It grants the imported Lambda role a right to consume messages via a resource-based policy (a `AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy` resource) on the Queue itself.

Comment: @fedonev as it is right now, no it won't; I get your point

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but have 1 or 2 problems. CDK requires two ARNs from the imported Lambda: (1) the Function execution Role's ARN and (2) the Function ARN.  You provide them with `lambda.Function.fromFunctionAttributes`.

**(1) Function execution Role ARN**: You *definitely* have a problem here. You need a reference the imported Lambda's *existing* execution `Role` via its ARN. You have created a new `Role`, which is not going to work. Instead, "import" the existing role with `iam.Role.fromRoleArn` A typical way to get a Role ARN is to export it as a [CloudFormation output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) and import it into `cdkStack`:

```js
const fn = lambda.Function.fromFunctionAttributes(this, `FetchMetadata`, {
  role: iam.Role.fromRoleArn(
    this,
    'ImportedRole',
    cdk.Fn.importValue('NameOfStackExportWithTheRoleARN')
  ),
  functionArn: fetchMetadataFnArn,
});
```

If the imported Lambda was not created with CloudFormation, a [SSM Parameter Store Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-su-create.html) would be a way to pass `cdkStack` the Role's ARN.  Or hardcode it.

**(2) Function ARN**:  You may have a problem here.  I am not familiar with the Amplify helpers.  You can diagnose whether `fetchMetadataFnArn` is correctly resolving by temporarily adding a `CfnOutput` to `cdkStack`:

```js
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'JustCheckingWhetherTheFunctionArnIsReolvingOK', {
  value: fetchMetadataFnArn,
});
```

CDK prints these outputs to the console at deploy-time.  Check to see if the ARN is what you expect.

Once you get the imported ARNs right, CDK can create the `AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy` and `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping` it needs to wire the Lambda to the Queue.

---

<sup>N.B. You can delete `queue.grantConsumeMessages(lambdaRole)` and `queue.grantConsumeMessages(fn)`.  They are redundant.  `fn.addEventSource(eventSource)` makes the grant under the hood.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The ideal approach to reference the ARN of the lambda function created via Amplify into CDK is to use the below approach assuming you are using AWS CDK v2

```
 const importFunction:AmplifyDependentResourcesAttributes = AmplifyHelpers.addResourceDependency(this, 
  amplifyResourceProps.category, 
  amplifyResourceProps.resourceName, 
  [
    {category: 'function', resourceName: <Name of the function>},
  ]
);
const arn=cdk.Fn.ref(retVal.function.<function_name>.Arn);
```

This part should replace below part in your code to get the ARN

```
cdk.Fn.ref(
  dependencies.function.fetchMetadata.Arn
)
```